# How can I tell FontForge to work with Korean characters instead of Latin/English?

Tags: fonts, font-forge, ttf

I'm using FontForge to convert **otf** fonts to **ttf**, it works fine if I'm working with "Latin/English type characters" but when I'm working with Korean the resulting ttf includes none of the characters (seems as if it only tries to convert Latin/English) and obviously the resulting filesize is close to zero.

How can I tell FontForge to work with Korean characters instead of Latin/English?

### The Process

```
fontforge -script ttf.pe
```

#### ttf.pe

```
Open("SourceHanSansKR-Bold.otf")
Generate("output/SourceHanSansKR-Bold.ttf")

Open("SourceHanSansKR-ExtraLight.otf")
Generate("output/SourceHanSansKR-ExtraLight.ttf")

Open("SourceHanSansKR-Heavy.otf")
Generate("output/SourceHanSansKR-Heavy.ttf")

Open("SourceHanSansKR-Light.otf")
Generate("output/SourceHanSansKR-Light.ttf")

Open("SourceHanSansKR-Medium.otf")
Generate("output/SourceHanSansKR-Medium.ttf")

Open("SourceHanSansKR-Normal.otf")
Generate("output/SourceHanSansKR-Normal.ttf")

Open("SourceHanSansKR-Regular.otf")
Generate("output/SourceHanSansKR-Regular.ttf")
```

### Font URL/Link

It's called "Adobe Source Han Sans Subset OTF - Korean OpenType/CFF font" and I downloaded it from the Arch Linux repo:

- [Direct download link (Arch Linux Repo)](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/adobe-source-han-sans-kr-fonts/download/)
- [Arch Linux Repo info page](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/adobe-source-han-sans-kr-fonts/)
- [Official GitHub Repo](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-sans)